# Slow page load after updating primefaces(-extension) from 6.2 to 8

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I am currently in the process of updating
primefaces from version 6.2 to 8.0.8
and primefaces-extensions from 6.2 to 8.0.5

I am following those [migration guides](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/../migrationguide/migrationguide)

**Now if I open any page, the layout has some problems at page load (only for a short moment, looks like styles that get applied after the page is loaded or m)**

Also, the rows of my datatables are rendered one after the other (10 rows now take ~2 seconds to be drawn/loaded/...)
In general, the application is a lot slower than with version 6.2

As if caching is no longer working (?)

What I have tried:

- leaving the version of primefaces-extension 6.2
  now the UI is working, but I get some ClassNotFound erros, so not acceptable for production
- updating to a newer version of primefaces (10)
  problem still exists
- updating primefaces to 7.0 and extensions to 7.0.3
  problem still exists
- looked at what changed from primefaces extension 6.2 to 8.0.8
  overwhelmed
- checked that `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` is set to `Production`
- webapp version is 3.0

Is there anything obvious, e.g. a setting that one could miss?

Comment: What PrimeFaces extensions components are you using?  Also are you using MOVE_SCRIPTS_TO_BOTTOM PF Setting?

See the performance guide for tweaks to make your app load faster: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/13_0_0/#/core/performance

Comment: I will try the performance improvements.
Regarding the layout problem i found out that the error occurs starting with primefaces-extension version 6.2.7, with 6.2.6 everything works fine;
I am using blockUI, layout, layoutPane, tooltip and clipboard.
(I took a look at the jar files, the files that changed from 6.2.6 to 6.2.7 are slideout.js, codemirror.js, fluidgrid.js,sheet.js, primefaces-extensions.js, layout.css) .. i tried MOVE_SCRIPTS_TO_BOTTOM  false and true, made no difference for the layout

Comment: its most likely this fix: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/536

But the PrimeFaces Extensions Showcase uses Layout for the site and you can see its not slow...

Comment: the problems could be fixed by using MOVE_SCRIPTS_TO_BOTTOM and adjusting the layout.css manually in the jar (not that great, but at least it gets the job done)